# css and js Gettiing reloaded on JQuery Pop up

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using a ajax to populate a div for creating a pop up using jQuery. Everything is working fine but the performance is very Bad. When I did an analysis using dynatrace I found out that the div which I populate using ajax is reloading the whole js and css files of the parent page. Is there anyway to avoid the reloading of these css and js file. PFB the ajax call which I use to populate a div  tag

```
 $.ajax( {
    type :"POST",
    url :$("input[name=reqContext]").val() + 'editshipment/show/index.html',
    data :val,
    cache :false,
    success : function(result) {
        $("#editShipmentBody").html(result);
       }
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is reloading all css and js files?

Answer (score 1):

You're posting to a HTML page - does this page contain links to the js and css files aswell? You probably don't need these if you are just populating a div since your preloaded (ie. before the ajax call) js and css will be applied.

Answer (score -1):

you can filter what to load in the ajax request like this:
make php conditions and add an "ajax" variable to the request url

```
url: "somephpfile.php?ajax"
```

inside your php

```
<?php $ajax = isset($_GET['ajax']); ?>
<?php if(! $ajax){ ?>
  <!--some things that you don't wanna "reload" on ajax requests-->
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" scr="somescript.js"></script>
   <style>...</style>
  </head>
  <body>
<?php } ?>

   <div>other stuff that you want actually load via ajax ..</div>


<?php if(! $ajax){ ?>
  </body>
<?php } ?>
```

the exact demo can be found here
http://www.klein-associes.com/grand_public/
the menu items load ajax and link to the same pages they load.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the responses. I was unnecessarily loading aroung 6-8 js and csses which was creating this performance impact. I removed those and there is a drastix improvement in performance :-)

Comment: You should probably submit your own answer or close this question then :-)